# Is it allowed to update a row of a fact table?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, fact

I am confused. Is an update for a row in a fact table recommended or just don't do it in general?

I have read that it can slow the process, because an update is slower than an insert. Other say that it is not that bad as some people think.

Is there an advice for 2021 with state of the art Ram/cpu/...?

Answer (score 2):

In general, fact records are a moment in time and shouldn't need to be updated, so if you regularly need to update fact records then there may be an issue with your design.

The 2 main cases where fact updates are justified are:

- Accumulating snapshot facts
- Data fixes, which obviously would be an infrequent activity

From a technical perspective, updates are slower than inserts but whether they are "too slow" depends on your specific circumstances - though given the available technology these days I doubt whether having to do updates would be an insurmountable problem in 99% of circumstances.

If you do need to regularly update a fact table you should ensure it has a single PK column, rather than a composite PK made up of many dimensional keys, as referencing this in your updates will be much faster than using a composite key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I got confused because of the accumulating fact tables. Kimball itself introduced them and nowadays guys say "do not update a fact table". This is kinda weird and it is going into different directions...